# Adding GraphicsObject to two ViewBoxes or QGraphicsViews

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

Ultimately I want pyqtgraph to display a single GraphicsObject simultaneously in several ViewBoxes, sharing a single scene.
At the same time I want to have some other GraphicsObjects in a single ViewBox only.

Something like this:

```
vb0 = ViewBox()
vb1 = ViewBox()

# shown only in first ViewBox vb0
local_item = GraphicsObject()
# shown in all ViewBoxes
global_item = GraphicsObject()

vb0.addItem(local_item)

assert vb0.scene() is vb1.scene()

# the magic function i am looking for
vb0.scene().addItemGlobally(global_item)
```

So very naively I looked into the ViewBox sourcecode and reproduced the steps for addItem() like here:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore as qc, QtGui as qg, QtWidgets as qw

class Polygon(pg.GraphicsObject):
    """Just a Triangle..."""

app = qw.QApplication([])

viewer = pg.GraphicsWindow()
vb0 = viewer.addViewBox(0, 0)
vb1 = viewer.addViewBox(0, 1)
viewer.show()

poly_yellow = Polygon((125, 125, 0, 255))

scene = vb0.scene()
added_items = vb1.addedItems = vb0.addedItems
child_group = vb1.childGroup = vb0.childGroup
child_group.setParent(scene)
child_group.itemsChangedListeners.append(vb1)

# here reproducing steps found in addItem() 
if scene is not poly_yellow.scene():
    scene.addItem(poly_yellow)

poly_yellow.setParentItem(child_group)
added_items.append(poly_yellow)

vb0.updateAutoRange()
# vb1.updateAutoRange()

# checking if ViewBoxes share relevant attributes
assert vb0.scene() is vb1.scene()
assert vb0.scene() is poly_yellow.scene()
assert vb0.addedItems is vb1.addedItems
assert vb0.childGroup is vb1.childGroup

app.exec_()
```

Running this gives me two ViewBoxes, but only vb0 showing the triangle. Also this approach would give me global only Items. Is there any way to get something like local/global items without re-implementing ViewBoxes completely?

**EDIT:** I think it is impossible to achieve what I want with pyqtgraph ViewBoxes. A transform of the global items must happen just before the painting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it is not easily doable using ViewBox. However, it is possible to us pyqtgraphs GraphicsView, implementing a lot of functionality found in the ViewBox class already.

My approach now is to generate as many GraphicsView as I need, and set them all to one scene via GraphicsView.setScene()

The scene contains the 'global' items, displayed in every View. The Viewspecific, local Items are drawn using the GraphicsView.drawBackground() function.

I haven't tested it to much, but it seems quite good working, for the case, were several thousend items are added to the scene, but only few items are drawn to the background.